# Setup a whole range of PHP if statements for code to pull from

Tags: php, arrays

I have a whole bunch of values, that need to correspond to some other values.
I've so far setup an array as per the below:

```
    $result = array(
            1 => 'Red',
            2 => 'Orange',
            3 => 'Yellow',
            4 => 'Green'
    );
```

I also have a variable, **$input** that provides a number value.

I need to figure out a way to say something like:

```
<?php if $input = any of the values in the array, then display its corresponding colour.
```

My array list will end up having hundreds of values in it, so if there is a much better way to achieve this I'm all ears. It just must be in PHP.

How could this best be achieved? Many thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished quite easily using the `isset` function:

```
<?php

$result = array(
    1 => 'Red',
    2 => 'Orange',
    3 => 'Yellow',
    4 => 'Green'
);

$input = 3;

if (isset($result[$input]))
    echo $result[$input] . PHP_EOL;
```

To find within a range:

```
$result = [
    '1-2' => 'Red',
    '2-5' => 'Orange',
    '6-9' => 'Yellow',
    '10-20' => 'Green'
];

$input = 8;

foreach ($result as $range => $colour) {
    $split = explode('-', $range);
    if ($input >= $split[0] && $input <= $split[1]) {
        echo $colour . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Note: This code would blow up if you accidentally had ranges overlap in some way.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks so much thats so simple. In all my searching I didnt find this anywhere, perhaps my search queries were not quite right. Really appreciate the help!

Comment: Also just wondering is it possible at all to add a range in my values of the array? Such as 1 to 2 => 'Red' ?

Comment: Yep that's also possible, I've edited my answer.

Comment: You are so awesome!!! Thank you so so much